# Is it possible to check access via URL or Click?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

Is there some way to identify when some route is access by event (like Click) or URL?

I need to block access when it's called by URL.

Example: if I type "www.example.com/shop/:id" redirect to "www.example.com/shop", only pass if I'm clicking in some button on "www.example.com/shop" view

```
{
  path: 'shop',
  children: [
    {path: '', component: ShopListComponent},
    {path: ':id', component: ShopViewComponent}
  ]
}
```

Comment: You can achieve this using a `Guard`

Comment: Yes, it can, but it's a bad thing.You don't know if user is coming from Angular and so you can't check the `route listener`. The best thing that you can do it's implement a `Guard`

Comment: @Silente13 so how can i make a guard to prevent access to :id only if i'm on 'shop' path?

Answer (score 0):

If that's the feature you want to achieve, then in principle using URL and router to display individual items is wrong.
URL is supposed to be resource locator and should represent some application state.

URLs can be shared and bookmarked to return to the location you were before.
To not break this principle and user expectations you should simply load an item in your view without using router.

However, if you insist on using router and simply preventing opening URL via address bar, then you should implement Route Guard with [CanActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) interface.

But how are you going to detect if user opened item via click?

One approach would be using service and tracking on which item user clicked on.
For example in your component

```
  onClick(itemId) {
    this.itemNavService.allowNavigatingToItem(itemId);
    this.router.navigate(['/shop', itemId]);

  }
```

Then in your Route Guard:

```
@Injectable()
class CanOpenItem implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private itemNavService: ItemNavService) {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean|UrlTree>|Promise<boolean|UrlTree>|boolean|UrlTree {
    return this.itemNavService.canActivate(route.params.id);
  }
}
```

and your service could be something like:

```
@Injectable()
class ItemNavService {
  allowNavigatingTo = null;


  allowNavigatingToItem(itemId) {
    this.allowNavigatingTo = itemId;
  }

  canActivate(itemId) {
    return this.allowNavigatingTo === itemId;
  }

}
```